# Remove subcategories from header navigation

Tags: magento

On website http://mpgautoparts.com, the subcategories are appearing on the navigation bar. How can I remove them so that it doesn't do it?

When I edit subcategory and select "No" for Include in Navigation Menu, it will remove from the header but also remove it from http://www.mpgautoparts.com/categories/ page too.

I'm not sure why it's removing from both.

[image]

Comment: http://www.mpgautoparts.com/categories/ seems be a homemade cms pages. Check in it for get an exclusion categories list

Answer (score 0):

You can set the maximal depth of the navigation menu here: System > Configuration > Catalog > Category Top Navigation. If you want it to show only the main categories set it to 0.